# How to update the chef-client version?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef client that is running chef 11.4.0, that means, when I run chef on the machine it says `Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.0`. I know that the latest chef gem is 11.8.0 (locally `knife --version` gives me `Chef: 11.8.0`), and I wanted to have the latest version running in the client, but I couldn't find any standard way to do that.

Sorry if the question doesn't make much sense, it might be that my understanding of the whole chef thing is not accurate.

Edit: I tried getting to the client machine and running `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install chef` as mentioned in https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Using+Chef+to+Upgrade+Chef but it says it's already the latest version.

Comment: Which apt repo are you using? Opscode's? That's only for Chef 10 and is not available for Chef 11 (which is a pity). Don't use that apt-repo anymore.

Comment: What about `sudo gem update chef`?

Comment: Don't use http://wiki.opscode.com as it is outdated and not managed.
Use http://docs.opscode.com/ instead.
Folks from #chef channel at IRC have advised me that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
$ chef-client -version
Chef: 11.4.0

$ curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash

$ chef-client -version
Chef: 11.8.0
```

The downloaded "install.sh" script will determine the correct OS and download the appropriate package for your platform. (These packages are all available from a S3 repository)

See also the [install page](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/) from the Chef site..

## Update

```
knife ssh 'name:[* TO *]' 'curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash'
```

If you sit behind a corporate firewall you can pull down the package for your platform and install it into you package repository. You are not compelled to use the "install.sh" script that is purely for convenience.

Comment: I see, but is this the correct procedure to update the chef version? I mean, the chef structure as a whole makes it necessary to at some point ssh into a client and manually update the chef version as you describe? I would think there's a better mechanism for that.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Chef is an agent based technology and therefore suffers from the standard chicken and egg problem. How does one get the agent installed without the agent present. This is where knife comes in (See update).

Comment: fair enough, accepted. It's a bit sad that this is the answer though, as it basically means "to update chef on the clients, you have to run a custom script that's not very evident from the documentation"

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Understood. Perhaps the chef documentation should do a better job of explaining how to maintain the client. Stephen has mentioned the updater cookbook, which I deeply suspect... It works great when it works.... At the end of the day I think you'll always need to have an external mechanism to keep agent based technologies up-to-date (I use rundeck, an SSH based automation tool. Used to brute force updates and reset broken chef clients). Sounds crazy to use more than one tech, but works for me.

Comment: We use this technique but also explicitly include the version we want to install, which is supported.  The curl command we do is: curl -LO https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh && sudo bash ./install.sh -v 11.8.2

Comment: One more thing, you could search by chef version i.e.
knife ssh 'chef_packages_chef_version:11.4.*' ...

Comment: You could try searching for the node attribute "node[chef_packages][chef][version]". I never tried it.

Answer (score 15):

That script takes argument. So you also may run it as:

```
(echo "version=11.12.8"; curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh) | sudo bash
```

to install specific version

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific version, try this:

```
# install chef 13
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -v 13
```

You can even downgrade if you are finding a newer version is too much work migrating to.

(Credits: http://ionrails.com/2013/04/19/downgrading-chef-client/)

Comment: I was looking for a specific major version and this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [omnibus_updater](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/omnibus_updater) cookbook.

Comment: But I really agree that updating chef-client is still a PITA. Having the packages in an (e.g.) apt repository from opscode would be my first choice.

Comment: I just want to make sure I got it right. For instance, I run knife and bootstrap a node today, it has chef 11.8.0. 6 months later the current chef version is 11.20.0, then I update the machine running knife (just update the chef gem) and bootstrap the node again, and it still has chef 11.8.0 (now old). And there's no default solution for that. Is that so?

Comment: When you bootstrap a node, the default bootstrap template installs the version you are running on your workstation (or set `knife[:bootstrap_version]`). I'd say you don't want to do manual upgrades (by running another `knife bootstrap`, but want to deploy it through chef itself). However, if you have a different chef version on your workstation, you will then deploy this to the node, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Indeed correct.
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
will try to get and install the latest client version on your system.

By which anyways, while executing tasks with chef-server. chef-client will never prompt you for any error like : chef-client version not updated or cant be used.